# Apply changes to a specific table only

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

There is a code that uses a single linq context objects to work with multiple tables. After changing some values, I need to update the them in DB. Is it achieved with a SubmitChanges function, that applies all the changes that made. The code looks kind of like this:

```
MyDBDataContext ctx = new MyDBDataContext(connectionString);

first_table_object first = (from f in ctx.first_table_objects select f).FirstOrDefault();
first.property = 1;

second_table_object second = (from s in ctx.second_table_objects select s).FirstOrDefault();
second.property = 2;

//ctx.SubmitChanges();
ctx.SubmitChangesOnlyToTheSecondTable();
```

Is it possible to update only one table instead of submitting all the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you can detach the object retrieved from the first table. You can achieve it by using [AsNoTracking()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx). This is will instruct EF to no take care of changes made on entities taken from `first_table_objects`

```
 first_table_object first = (ctx.first_table_objects.AsNoTracking().Select(s => s)).FirstOrDefault()
```